# mock flask-sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, pytest

I'm getting an error of Module not found when trying to create a test function to mock the get method of sqlalchemy query (with pytest)

example:

```
from mock import patch     
@patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__')
def test_get_all(queryMock):
    assert True
```

When running pytest i get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty'
```

I'm using the 3.0.2 version of Flask-SQLAlchemy. So i just changed to version 2.5.1 and it worked.  However i think would be good to use the latest version. Is there any other way to mock the sql-alchemy query that works with the latest versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flask_sqlalchemy.model._QueryProperty.__get__` instead of `flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__`. This will resolve your issue as _QueryProperty class has been moved into model.

```
from mock import patch     
@patch('flask_sqlalchemy.model._QueryProperty.__get__')
def test_get_all(queryMock):
    assert True
```